# Persist Firebase anonymous login on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security

I don't want my users to have to create an account, but I want to remember who they are session to session. I was hoping to create an anonymous login and store the token in NSUserDefaults. From what I see the token will expire, and I can not refresh this token.

How should I persist an anonymous login?

My next option was to use email/password authentication and generate a fake email using a UUID. Then storing the fake email/password on the user's device.

Comment: Firebase automatically persists login session after you auth anonymously, and retains the session until the expiration time specified in your Firebase dashboard. Upon starting up your app, you can get the authentication state of the user with `ref.authData`. If that's not working as expected, try reaching out to support@firebase.com.

Comment: @RobDiMarco you comment was mentioned in their docs. I was wondering how to persist the login beyond the expiration date, or have anonymous logins never expire.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you wish to have them never expire, I would recommend modifying the expiration TTL in your Firebase dashboard to be effectively infinite, or suggest a custom authentication solution using your own servers.

Comment: @RobDiMarco, I'll use your suggestion and set it to 1000 months, that should do.