# How long do anonymous accounts using google firebase stay logged in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a website and using [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com), when I sign in with google the login stays persistent between pages but with anonymous accounts after you change pages you don't stay logged in. Is there a way to fix/change this?

Comment: I believe there is a setting in your Firebase dashboard? There are a couple of questions on this i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106812/persist-firebase-anonymous-login-on-ios

Comment: @aug that answer applies to Firebase Authentication 1.x and 2.x. This question is about the new Firebase at firebase.google.com, where the behavior is different.

Comment: @PlanetVaster without seeing the minimal code that reproduces your problem, we can only speculate on how to fix this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Not really, you can't set the amount of time guest accounts stay logged in via code, and the new 3.x doesn't have any server side settings only 1.x and  2.x.